# how to upgrade from one role to another role in drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

i have two types of roles in my site. they are

1)free user

2)premium user

If user registered as "free user" and then he/she want to upgrade their role to "premium user" from "free user".how can i implement this feature in my site? .is there any module for that?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

[LM_PayPal](http://drupal.org/project/lm_paypal) is another module that allows you to change roles based on a user paying a subscription fee.

It is not as comprehensive as the Ubercart route, but it is possibly easier to set up. It only works with PayPal payments, though.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your request, you want to promote user to role premium after a payment?

Ubercart features:

> Product features to add file downloads, role promotions, and more to products.

Ubercart module page: http://drupal.org/project/ubercart

You also may want to check out this post:
http://drupal.org/node/652472